# Why has $\sup_{s \in (0,t)} B_s$ the same distribution as $\sup_{s \in (0,t)} B_s-B_t$ for a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Here on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_laws_(Wiener_process)#Equivalence_of_the_second_and_third_laws) is claimed that the process $X_t:=\sup_{s \in (0,t)} B_s-B_t$ is distributed like $\vert B_t \rvert$ where $B_t$ is standard Brownian motion.

On the other hand, it is claimed [here in Corollary $6.21$](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/mynotes.pdf) that $\sup_{s \in (0,t)} B_s$ is distributed like $\vert B_t \rvert.$

So how is it possible that $\sup_{s \in (0,t)} B_s-B_t$ is distributed like $\sup_{s \in (0,t)} B_s.$ There seems to be something wrong with probability.

If you have any further questions, please let me know.

Comment: What, exactly, is the contradiction?  Lots of unequal random variables have the same distribution.  I think another thing that  would bother you is that $B_t-tB_1$ is distributed as $B_{1-t}-(1-t)B_0$.

Comment: @kimchilover but here we have that $X$ and $X+Y$ have the same distribution where $Y$ is non-trivial.

Comment: In general, what's wrong with that?  Take for example  $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=-2X$. Here  $X$ and $Y$ are far from independent, *as are* $ \sup_{s\in(0,t)}B_s$ and $B_t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each fixed $t>0$ the process

$$W_s := B_{t-s}-B_t, \qquad s \in [0,t],$$

defines a Brownian motion $(W_s)_{s \in [0,t]}$. In particular, $(B_s)_{s \in [0,t]}$ equals in distribution $(W_s)_{s \in [0,t]}$, and so

$$\sup_{s \in [0,t]} B_s \stackrel{d}{=} \sup_{s \in [0,t]} W_s \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sup_{s \in [0,t]} B_s-B_t.$$

This shows that the random variables $\sup_{s \in [0,t]} B_s$ and $\sup_{s \in [0,t]} B_s-B_t$ have the same distribution.